# CSS header text not responding on website

Tags: css

I do this code

```
h6 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 1;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

but for some reason my code isn't responding. Why is this?

Comment: can you please upload html because its nothing seems wrong here.

Comment: yeah nothing wrong

Comment: Can you please share a demo URL

Answer (score 0):

write the style inside the style tag. if you are using internal style

or else if you are using external style sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-your-style-sheet" type="text/css" />


<html>
    <body>
        <style>
        h6 {
          font-size: 30px;
          padding: 100px;
          margin: 0;
          position: fixed;
          text-align: left;
          border: 1px solid black;
          text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        </style>
        <h6>answer</h6>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me. please share your html code as well with what exactly error you are getting thanks.

```css
        h6 {
          font-size: 30px;
          padding: 100px;
          margin: 0;
          position: fixed;
          text-align: left;
          border: 1px solid black;
          text-transform: capitalize;
        }
```

```html
<h6>answer</h6>
```

Comment: h6 {
         font-size: 30px;
         margin: 0;
         position: fixed;
         text-align: left;
         border: 1px solid black;
         text-transform: capitalize;
       }